# RJ45 between wall sockets

Tags: networking, ethernet, rj-45

I have installed a 70 meter long RJ45 CAT6 cable between my house and my garage.

The setup I'm trying to achieve is very simple:

Router <--> eth cat6 (industry crimped) <--> wall socket <--> eth cat6 (70 meters) <--> wall socket <--> eth cat6 (industry crimped) <--> server

The 70 meter cable was crimped by me but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is a pictured attached:[image]

The weirdest thing is that it was working the first time I booted the server but since two days it stopped working.

Do you know if my crimping is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Borrow a cable tester.

Comment: Not to be rude, but how can we possibly answer your question by seeing a single blurry picture? Borrow a cable tester as suggested. That is how professionals do it.

Answer (score 0):

For future references: the problem came from one copper cable not being in contact with its pin inside the wall socket...